# Inserir cabeçalho em planilha com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso inserir uma imagem no cabeçalho do arquivo xlsx que é gerado pelo Python com uma rotina de captar dados do banco e transformar em relatório.
Estou usando esse método alternativo, onde insere na primeira linha, porém, quando coloco o arquivo para imprimir não fica como deveria, que no caso, seria no cabeçalho da página.

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\ARQUIVO.xlsx')

ws = wb ["Sheet1"]

img_logo = r"C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\CROSS.jpg"

imagem_logo = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_logo)

img_hpf = r"C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\FPH_VZ_AR.jpg"

imagem_hpf = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image(img_hpf)

ws.add_image(imagem_logo, 'A1')

ws.add_image(imagem_hpf, 'D1')


wb.save(r'C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\ARQUIVO.xlsx')


wb.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei como fazer, inclusive muito mais fácil e pratico do que eu pensei:

*ws.PageSetup.CenterHeaderPicture.FileName = (r'C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\IMAGENS\D_Cabeçalho Excel Horizontal.png')
ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&G" ws.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.FileName = (r'C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\IMAGENS\Rodapé Excel Horizontal.png') ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&G"*

E depois é só ajustar as margens da página:

*ws.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 50.0 
ws.PageSetup.TopMargin = 70.0 
ws.PageSetup.RightMargin = 50.0 
ws.PageSetup.Zoom = False*

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que nem o `openpyxl`, nem nenhuma outra biblioteca de criação de arquivos XLSX (ou ODS, que também são planilhas) fornece um nível de controle sobre posicionamento e redimensionamento de imagens e estilo  -todas elas focam mais no conteúdo das células.

Dá para tentar fazer algumas experiências com o estilo (style) da célula onde você põe a imagem - mas a docuemntação do OpenPyXL não ajuda muito - https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html

Você tem outras  duas abordagens pra tentar evoluir seu problema

## 1 - Corrigir o XML da planilha "manualmente"

Tanto arquivos "xlsx" quando "ods" são compostos de um "zip" de arquivos XML, onde está realmente o conteúdo. Esses XML vão ter vários atributos e tags específicas onde ficam guardados os parâmetros de posicionamento e formatação de itens, que normalmente são editados manualmente no programa de planilha (no caso, o Excel).

Então a sugestão seria, depois de criar uma planilha como você faz acima, abrir a mesma no excel, posicionar a imagem como deseja, e salvar como outra planilha -
descomprimir as duas planilhas, lado a lado, (no windows você pode descomprimir com o mesmo programa que trata arquivos zip - seja winrar, winzip, etc..., talvez seja necessário renomear a planilha pra mudar a extensão), e, com as planilhas descomprimidas, tentar localizar a diferença no XML para a formatação da sua imagem  - podem ser uma ou mais tags, e vários atributos -

**nesse ponto**, se você conseguir identificar os atributos que o excel usa para posicionar e dar o tamanho da imagem talvez seja possível usar os recursos de *estilo* do OpenPyXL para formatar a imagem (como está acima). Esse certametne seria o caminho mais viável de todos!

**Senão**, verificar se manipulando o xml através do Python consegue recriar e alterar os tags no XML como é gerado pelo OpenPyXL para chegar nos mesmos valores que o Excel (use a biblitoeca `zipfile` para "abrir" o xlsx e `xml.etree` para ler e alterar o xml, e depois `zipfile` para recriar o xlsx.

Não vai ser uma tarefa fácil!

## 2 - Interagir programaticamente com o Excel

Gerar a planilha com o OpenPyXl normalmente, e depois usar interação direta do Python com o Excel aberta através do win32con - que permite que você chame "funções" da interface do Excel a partir do Python, para mandar o excel abrir sua planilha, posicionar a imagem como necessário, e salva-la de volta.

Pode dar menos trabalho - mas vai ser bem chato também.

Aqui tem uma lista de recursos e bibliotecas para trabalhar integrando Python e Excel - pode até ser que alguma delas permita o posicionamento da imagem de forma mais direta:

https://www.pyxll.com/blog/tools-for-working-with-excel-and-python/

Comment: Encontrei como fazer, inclusive muito mais fácil e pratico do que eu pensei:

ws.PageSetup.CenterHeaderPicture.FileName = (r'C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\IMAGENS\D_Cabeçalho Excel Horizontal.png')

ws.PageSetup.CenterHeader = "&G"

ws.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.FileName = (r'C:\Users\daymon.rebac\Rotinas\IMAGENS\Rodapé Excel Horizontal.png')

ws.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&G"

E depois é só ajustar as margens da página:

ws.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 50.0

ws.PageSetup.TopMargin = 70.0

ws.PageSetup.RightMargin = 50.0

ws.PageSetup.Zoom = False

Comment: você pode postar esse comentário como uma resposta e dar o aceite nele  - ajuda quem vier depois (e você ainda ganha pontos). Folheando a documentação do openpyxl, eu não vi esses métodos, então se junto você colocar links direto para essas partes da documentação, ajuda mais ainda.